# CNTK: Applying average pooling over LSTM output

Tags: cntk

I am trying to apply an average pooling function over the outputs of an LSTM for a sequence:

```
  Sequential([
            Embedding(emb_dim),
            pooling(Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim), go_backwards=False), PoolingType_Average, (hidden_dim,)),
            Dense(num_labels)
        ])
```

When I was just using the last element of the sequence it was working without problems:

```
Sequential([
            Embedding(emb_dim),
            sequence.last(Recurrence(LSTM(hidden_dim), go_backwards=False)),
            Dense(num_labels)
        ])
```

a. Is the addition of pooling int he network definition correct and does the shape I set describe the operation I am trying to perform? (i.e. to average the vectors coming from the LSTM for each sample in the sequence)
b. The format of my input data that worked when using sequence.last is the following (for 1 sequence). Does it need to change to apply mean pooling?

```
1       |x 5:1  |y 1 0 0 0 0
1       |x 414:1
1       |x 8:1
```

The error I get is:

File .../model_training.py", line 55, in train
    criterion.placeholders[1]: Input(num_labels, dynamic_axes=[Axis.default_batch_axis()])})
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/utils/swig_helper.py", line 58, in wrapper
    result = f(*args, **kwds)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/ops/functions.py", line 449, in replace_placeholders
    return super(Function, self).replace_placeholders(substitutions)
  File ".../anaconda3/envs/cntk-py35/lib/python3.5/site-packages/cntk/cntk_py.py", line 1246, in replace_placeholders
    return _cntk_py.Function_replace_placeholders(self, placeholderReplacements)
RuntimeError: Currently if an operand of a elementwise operation has any dynamic axes, those must match the dynamic axes of the other operands

Answer (score 0):

Pooling only works with static axes. There is a branch with a `sequence.pooling` operation that should be available in master around the end of January (2017). You can also do average pooling with a recurrence. This [example](https://github.com/Microsoft/CNTK/wiki/Implement-an-attention-mechanism) pools with a "learned" average pooling via a recurrence.